# How to get information about symbol scoping in Julia while compilation?

Tags: scope, compilation, julia

I'm interested in understanding how Julia determines the scope of each symbol during compilation. I'd like to get detailed information about the scope of every symbol instance in the code, ideally as output from the compilation process itself.

1. Is there a built-in way in Julia to get information about symbol scoping during compilation?
2. Are there any flags or compiler options that can be used to generate this information as output?
3. If not, are there any recommended approaches or tools for analyzing symbol scope within the Julia compiler pipeline?
4. Any insights or references on how the Julia compiler handles symbol resolution and scope determination would be greatly appreciated!

Here's what I've tried:

- I searched the Julia documentation and online resources, but I couldn't find any built-in features or flags to achieve this.

Comment: https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/variables-and-scoping/

Answer (score 1):

If you want to discover that the same variable name is used in different scopes you could try to use `@code_warntype`:

Consider the code that yields `5`.

```
function f()
    x = 5
    for x in 2:2
       print(x)
    end
    x
end
```

You could discover that some scoping issues are around x by running:

```
julia> @code_warntype f()
MethodInstance for f()
  from f() @ Main REPL[25]:1
Arguments
  #self#::Core.Const(f)
Locals
  @_2::Union{Nothing, Tuple{Int64, Int64}}
  x@_3::Int64
  x@_4::Int64
Body::Int64
1 ─       (x@_3 = 5)
...
```

You can see that `x` has different meaning in different scopes by observing `x@_3` and `x@_4`.

Similarly you could peek at AST of `f`:

```
julia> Base.uncompressed_ast(methods(f).ms[1])
CodeInfo(
    @ REPL[39]:2 within `f`
1 ─       x@_3 = 5
│   @ REPL[39]:3 within `f`
│   %2  = 2:2
│         @_2 = Base.iterate(%2)
│   %4  = @_2 === nothing
│   %5  = Base.not_int(%4)
└──       goto #4 if not %5
2 ┄ %7  = @_2
│         x@_4 = Core.getfield(%7, 1)
│   %9  = Core.getfield(%7, 2)
│   @ REPL[39]:4 within `f`
│         Main.print(x@_4)
│   @ REPL[39]:5 within `f`
│         @_2 = Base.iterate(%2, %9)
│   %12 = @_2 === nothing
│   %13 = Base.not_int(%12)
└──       goto #4 if not %13
3 ─       goto #2
    @ REPL[39]:6 within `f`
4 ┄       return x@_3
)
```

Another useful feature is `Base.@locals`.
Consider this function:

```
function f()
    x = 5
    for y in 2:2
        @show Base.@locals
    end
end
```

Than you have:

```
julia> f()
#= REPL[29]:4 =# Base.@locals() = Dict{Symbol, Any}(:y => 2, :x => 5)
```

I believe this is all you can do without writing some your own package for that. Maybe someone will add something to that list.